# How can i position the image as center even resize the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to place the image as center of the screen as with calculation like

```
       var wh = jQuery(window).innerHeight();
        var ww = jQuery(window).innerWidth();
        var fh = jQuery('.drop').innerHeight();
        var fw = jQuery('.drop').innerWidth();
```

I am not sure where i did the mistake. For the resize the window as i tried with

```
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
                var wh = jQuery(window).innerHeight();
                var ww = jQuery(window).innerWidth();
                var fh = jQuery('.drop').innerHeight();
                var fw = jQuery('.drop').innerWidth();
            });
```

But that above script won't help even if i resize the window also image doesn't align to center.

Is there is a way to show the image as center even if i resize the window.

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aB8yq/14/)**

Comment: U can do this with css.

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to this?? http://jsfiddle.net/aB8yq/21/ - @Vicky

Comment: I didn't see you used (window).resize() in your fiddle....

Comment: Thanks I removed from fiddle that resize is in question

Comment: You should have mention that u need only in Script or CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try it like,

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.drop2').css({
        position: 'absolute',
        left: ($(window).width() - $('.drop2').outerWidth()) / 2,
        top: ($(window).height() - $('.drop2').outerHeight()) / 2,
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/vvk3p/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with css alone:

```
div{
  background: red;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBBJM/1/)** and **[Article](http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/)**

Answer (score 0):

I had done like this in my project.

```
.side {
height: 357px;
background-color: red;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
}
.middle {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -250px;
background:url('a.jpg') no-repeat;
width:500px;
height:357px;
}


<div class="side">
<div class="middle"></div>
```

Comment: This only works if you know the exact height/width of the element to be centered, which OP would appear not to as he is creating the elementdynamically